# Testing and running in .netcore 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So i'm developing a firewall for my thesis. My first idea was to port pfsense to .net core but it was to difficult to analyze al that code.

Of course my application will run on linux specifically ubuntu or self made busybox.

As for my firewall package I will use iptables.
i'm working in visual studio 2017 .net core 2.1 and developing in windows.

My question is How am I able to test my app in linux enviroment. 
For example my dashboard will have system statuses like cpu ram and stuff -> for this i used " read.readalllines("/proc/cpuinfo") " which is ofcourse a linux file. the same for iptables. i have my commandbuilder class which make the iptables command but it need to be executed and tested. So Again how am i able to test this

kind regards

Comment: As a student, apply JetBrains Rider free license and use that to debug .NET Core apps on all major platforms. You can also use VSCode to debug on Linux https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md

Comment: Thx probably this can help I already have vscode on my linux laptop so i could use this.